# View.phtml don´t show attribute if empty

Tags: attributes

I have made an attribute called replacement_sku to be show on the product page.
My problem is that I would like it only to be visible if there is content and not visible if empty.

Hope someone can help me with some kind of if statement for that.
I use the Ultimo template and Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an example that should work for this:

```
<?php if($attrValue = $_product->getData('replacement_sku')): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Replacement Sku') ?>: <span><?php echo $attrValue ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have tried to use the if statement, but it does not seem to work.
My product page gets blank.

Comment: sry! there was actually one closing brace missing. just upadted it!

Comment: It is inserted in the view.phtml file correct?
know some about magento but much to learn.
Good someone will help

Comment: What if I only wants replacement_sku to be shown if there are content and not shown if empty?

Comment: You solved my problem. The last was my own mistake.

Comment: thats exaclty for that: the if statement asks if the "replacement_sku" is set to some value, and if it is, it outputs everything inside the if

Comment: I did not remove the old one.
Thank you very very much for your help :)

Comment: no problem. glad I could help you :)